# onResume and onLaunch is not getting called in Flutter firebase_messaging 6.0.13

Tags: android, api, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase_messaging 6.0.13 plugin in flutter project. onMessage is working fine but onResume and onLaunch is not getting called. Following is my plugin configuration code

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");

  },
  onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");

  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");

  },
);
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
       print(token);
});
```

Following is myBackgroundMessageHandler

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
  }

  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
  }

  // Or do other work.
}
```

Following is the payload I'm sending from api.

```
var payload = new
            {
                to = "fD637iNwLqA:APA91bEtxdMTNC805-9-pYONFedGSPakpf_KcCNFrzAlS6D229NC1ubb7vwDMtR1NG2vKc9tHeNrN50BVmy-Q6tlvO35OwFbaIPt2s_PO7cF-qGmgMwUr-A5F2R_eKxz2XCPE4jtal_B",
                priority = "high",
                content_available = true,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta tempor congue. Mauris interdum enim a convallis pulvinar. Nullam pharetra ipsum non nulla tristique commodo. In non sem vel nisi sollicitudin tincidunt. Sed non convallis ligula, fermentum placerat risus. Cras a tellus in eros viverra ornare.",
                    title = "Neque porro quisquam est ",
                    badge = 1
                },
                data = new
                {
                    body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta tempor congue. Mauris interdum enim a convallis pulvinar. Nullam pharetra ipsum non nulla tristique commodo. In non sem vel nisi sollicitudin tincidunt. Sed non convallis ligula, fermentum placerat risus. Cras a tellus in eros viverra ornare.",
                    title = "Neque porro quisquam est ",
                    click_action = "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                    id = "1",
                    status = "01 May 2020",
                    image = "https://ibin.co/2t1lLdpfS06F.png",

                }

            };
```

I have consulted almost all online forums but its still not working for me.

Comment: It must be past lunch time then.

Comment: Thank you @Nicolas for your reply. I didn't get you. what past lunch time and how can I control it ?

Comment: I'm just joking with your title, that's all :)

Comment: I just noticed :)

Comment: I noticed one thing. I'm getting following when I click on notification message from system tray.

**missing default notification channel metadata in androidmanifest. default value will be used flutter**

Comment: seems like nobody has answer to my question :(

Comment: Flutter is a new technology so that's what happens, there's not many experts. I never used it so I can't really help you.